# purge oldest logs in logrotation

Tags: logrotate

I am purging logs that are older than 30 days by using `maxage` command

But I want to satisfy this criteria `purge oldest logs if number of log files in total reaches 50`

If anyone can help me with this would be helpful as I have no much knowledge on `logrotation`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your logfiles do not include date in the filename, adding `rotate 50` will keep up to 50 copies.

```
rotate count
          Log files are rotated count times before being removed
```